# The meaning of "une variation extraphonologique combinatoire"

Tags: sens, phonétique

I'm reading Éléments de Phonologie française by G. Gougenheim and I don't understand the term *variation extraphonologique combinatoire.* Here's the context:

> [...] il n'y a en français qu'un phonème *l*, bien qu'à côté de l'*l* sonore habituel il existe un *l* sourd chuchoté en fin de mot après une occlusive sourde ou un f (oncle, ample, souffle)[...]
>
> Nous avons vu que l'opposition *l* sonore - *l* sourd est **une variation extraphonologique combinatoire.** Il y a aussi **variation extraphonologique combinatoire** dans l'opposition des noms de nombre six et dix avec *s* à la fin du groupe de mots (ils sont six; j'en vois dix) et des mêmes noms de nombre avec *z* en liaison (six hommes, dix enfants).

Can someone elaborate on this? If I understood this correctly, there is only one phoneme /l/ in French although it can be pronounced in different ways. Why wouldn't those two *l*s be two different phonemes?

Comment: Je n'ai pas le contexte, mais je comprends « une variation par appariement avec d'autres lettres, ou début ou fin de syllabe, de mot ou de phrase ».  Le *r* est un autre exemple qui a plusieurs variétés « combinatoires », bien qu'il soit usuellement assimilé à un seul phonème, généralement noté /ʁ/. Le fait qu'il n'y ait qu'un seul phonème signifie dans les deux cas qu'il n'y a pas besoin de faire la distinction entre les différentes réalisations dans une entrée de dictionnaire, le contexte sonore (et parfois régional) étant suffisant pour qu'un locuteur habitué à la langue sache le prononcer.

Comment: Pourquoi pas deux phonèmes différents ? Ha! Si tu fais le tour des ouvrages de référence, tu trouveras pas moins de 6 définitions pour *phonème*... Il y en est certainement une pour laquelle, tu as en fait 2 phonèmes distincts... Après étant dit que je n'y connais rien là-dedans et encore moins précisément le système de Gougenheim (qui n'en est qu'un parmi d'autres) j'ai toujours associé (mais de façon possiblement très réductrice) la *variation extraphonologique combinatoire* à l'**allophonie**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a term particular to Gougenheim's own framework. A more theory neutral way of stating it would simply be "allophony".

Gougenheim distinguishes between **oppositions phonologiques** and **variations extraphonologiques**. The firsts are meaningful, functional distinctions (i.e. they differentiate phonemes), the seconds don't carry meaning and are outside the phonology of a language (hence *extra*phonologiques - in other words, they're phones).

He distinguishes between four  **variations extraphonologiques**:

1. **variations extraphonologiques combinatoires**: Despite what the term "combinatoire may imply, he doesn't just mean assimilation by this (for example, the nasalisation of /g/ to [ŋ] in "longuement") but every phenomenon by which a phoneme is realised differently in a language (for example the different realisations of /p/ in English in [pʰ]it and in s[p]it).
2. **variations extraphonologiques stylistiques**: The different ways a phoneme might be realised by the same speaker in different registers of a language. For example, the same person might realise "l'autre personne" as /loːtpɛχ'sɔn/ in a casual conversation, /loːtχəpɛχ'sɔn/ when reading aloud and /loːtχəpɛχ'sɔnə/ when reading poetry aloud. Today we'd simply call it stylistic variation.
3. **variations extraphonologiques individuelles**: What we today call "free variation": something that individual speakers say in a few different manners (sometimes switching apparently randomly between variants). A good example in French would be whether the final consonant of fait, août or almanach is pronounced.
4. **variations extraphonologiques concomitantes**: Today we'd call that "sandhi": in French, elision and liaison are examples. Including sandhi phenomenons in variations is criticable and Gougenheim has been criticized for it.

For a recent review of Gougenheim's theories of phonology, see Peter Swiggers' 2016 paper, "[De Prague à Strasbourg : Phonétique et phonologie du français chez Georges Gougenheim et Georges Straka](https://journals.openedition.org/ml/1459)"

---

And yes, that paragraph implies there's two (non meaningful ways to pronounce the phoneme /l/ in French, one that's voiced (like /z/ or /d/) and used in most contexts, and another that's voiceless (like /s/ or /t/) in the word final clusters /kl/, /tl/ and /pl/. Those are two different phones, but not two different phonemes because no two words can ever be distinguished by a voicing distinction of /l/ in French.

For them to be different phonemes (une opposition phonologique, in Gougenheim's words), you'd need them to potentially appear in the same place in a word or syllable, but that's not the case here. An example of an Language with such a distinction is Old English, where the only difference between land (modern land) and hlant (modern lant, a rarer word for urine) was the difference in voicing of l.

Comment: Thanks so much for making this crystal clear!